# How to create readable result of group function in RethinkDB without group and reduction field?

Tags: rethinkdb, reql

I have a query that uses `group()` function:

```
...group('a','b','c','na').count()
```

the now the result is returns like in the form of *group* and *reduction* like this:

[image]

How can I get result without group and reduce in the form of

```
{
"na": 1285
"c" : 487
"b" : 746
"a" : 32
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I think you're misunderstanding what group does.

The `group` command takes a property and groups documents by that property. So, for example, if you wanted to group documents by the `a` property, that would look something like this:

```
{
  a: 1
}, {
  a: 1
}, {
  a: 1
}, {
  a: 2
}
```

Then you would run the following query:

```
r.table(...).group('a').count().ungroup()
```

Which would result in:

```
[
  {
    "group": 1 ,
    "reduction": 3
  },
  {
    "group": 2 ,
    "reduction": 1
  }
]
```

By passing multiple arguments to `group` you are telling it to make distinct groups for all those properties. So you you have the following documents:

```
  [ {
    a: 1, b: 1
  }, {
    a: 1, b: 1
  }, {
    a: 1, b: 2
  }, {
    a: 2, b: 1
  }]
```

And you group them by `a` and `b`:

```
r.table(...).group('a', 'b').count().ungroup()
```

You will get the following result:

```
[{
  "group": [ 1 , 1 ] ,
  "reduction": 2
},
{
  "group": [ 1 , 2 ] ,
  "reduction": 1
},
{
  "group": [ 2 , 1 ] ,
  "reduction": 1
}]
```

**Your Answer**

So, when you do `.group('a','b','c','na').count()`, you're grouping them by those 4 properties. If you want the following result:

```
{
"na": 1285
"c" : 487
"b" : 746
"a" : 32
}
```

Then your documents should look something like this:

```
[{
  property: 'a'
}, {
  property: 'c'
}, {
  property: 'na'
}, 
...
]
```

And then you would group them in the following way:

```
r.table(...).group('property').count().ungroup()
```